# Counting email addresses with different status

Tags: c#, performance, linq, t-sql

I want to count email addresses with different status. I use ASP.NET MVC and this query is supposed to run every 5 minutes on these tables, which every table is on different .ndf files. About 5 million records will be inserted into email address table every day.

Is this query good enough, in terms of performance? You can also suggest any other query or ways.

```linq
var query = from p in sentMailPagingBiz.FetchMulti()
        join s in emailAddressBiz.FetchMulti() on p.Id equals s.SentMailPaging_Id
        where p.SentMail_Id == 5648
        group s by s.SentMailPaging_Id
        into g
        select new
        {
            All = g.Count(),
            ReadyToSend = g.Count(q => q.Status_Id == 1),
            Sent = g.Count(q => q.Status_Id == 2),
            Rejected = g.Count(q => q.Status_Id == 3),
            Queued = g.Count(q => q.Status_Id == 4),
            SoftBounce = g.Count(q => q.Status_Id == 5),
            HardBounce = g.Count(q => q.Status_Id == 6),
        };
```

Diagram:

> [image: DB Diagram]

Generated query:

```sql
  SELECT 
        1 AS [C1], 
  [Project6].[C1] AS [C2], 
  [Project6].[C2] AS [C3], 
  [Project6].[C3] AS [C4], 
  [Project6].[C4] AS [C5], 
  [Project6].[C5] AS [C6], 
  [Project6].[C6] AS [C7], 
  [Project6].[C7] AS [C8]
  FROM ( SELECT 
[Project5].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project5].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project5].[C3] AS [C3], 
[Project5].[C4] AS [C4], 
[Project5].[C5] AS [C5], 
[Project5].[C6] AS [C6], 
(SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM  [dbo].[SentMailsPagings] AS [Extent13]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SentMailsEmailAddresses] AS [Extent14] ON [Extent13].[Id] = [Extent14].[SentMailsPaging_Id]
    WHERE (5648 = [Extent13].[SentMail_Id]) AND ([Project5].[SentMailsPaging_Id] = [Extent14].[SentMailsPaging_Id]) AND (6 = [Extent14].[SentMailsEmailAddressStatus_Id])) AS [C7]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project4].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project4].[SentMailsPaging_Id] AS [SentMailsPaging_Id], 
    [Project4].[C2] AS [C2], 
    [Project4].[C3] AS [C3], 
    [Project4].[C4] AS [C4], 
    [Project4].[C5] AS [C5], 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM  [dbo].[SentMailsPagings] AS [Extent11]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SentMailsEmailAddresses] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent11].[Id] = [Extent12].[SentMailsPaging_Id]
        WHERE (5648 = [Extent11].[SentMail_Id]) AND ([Project4].[SentMailsPaging_Id] = [Extent12].[SentMailsPaging_Id]) AND (5 = [Extent12].[SentMailsEmailAddressStatus_Id])) AS [C6]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project3].[SentMailsPaging_Id] AS [SentMailsPaging_Id], 
        [Project3].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [Project3].[C3] AS [C3], 
        [Project3].[C4] AS [C4], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM  [dbo].[SentMailsPagings] AS [Extent9]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[SentMailsEmailAddresses] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent9].[Id] = [Extent10].[SentMailsPaging_Id]
            WHERE (5648 = [Extent9].[SentMail_Id]) AND ([Project3].[SentMailsPaging_Id] = [Extent10].[SentMailsPaging_Id]) AND (4 = [Extent10].[SentMailsEmailAddressStatus_Id])) AS [C5]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project2].[SentMailsPaging_Id] AS [SentMailsPaging_Id], 
            [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [Project2].[C3] AS [C3], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM  [dbo].[SentMailsPagings] AS [Extent7]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[SentMailsEmailAddresses] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent7].[Id] = [Extent8].[SentMailsPaging_Id]
                WHERE (5648 = [Extent7].[SentMail_Id]) AND ([Project2].[SentMailsPaging_Id] = [Extent8].[SentMailsPaging_Id]) AND (3 = [Extent8].[SentMailsEmailAddressStatus_Id])) AS [C4]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project1].[SentMailsPaging_Id] AS [SentMailsPaging_Id], 
                [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
                (SELECT 
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM  [dbo].[SentMailsPagings] AS [Extent5]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[SentMailsEmailAddresses] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[Id] = [Extent6].[SentMailsPaging_Id]
                    WHERE (5648 = [Extent5].[SentMail_Id]) AND ([Project1].[SentMailsPaging_Id] = [Extent6].[SentMailsPaging_Id]) AND (2 = [Extent6].[SentMailsEmailAddressStatus_Id])) AS [C3]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
                    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [SentMailsPaging_Id], 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                        FROM  [dbo].[SentMailsPagings] AS [Extent3]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SentMailsEmailAddresses] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent4].[SentMailsPaging_Id]
                        WHERE (5648 = [Extent3].[SentMail_Id]) AND ([GroupBy1].[K1] = [Extent4].[SentMailsPaging_Id]) AND (1 = [Extent4].[SentMailsEmailAddressStatus_Id])) AS [C2]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Extent2].[SentMailsPaging_Id] AS [K1], 
                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                        FROM  [dbo].[SentMailsPagings] AS [Extent1]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[SentMailsEmailAddresses] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[SentMailsPaging_Id]
                        WHERE 5648 = [Extent1].[SentMail_Id]
                        GROUP BY [Extent2].[SentMailsPaging_Id]
                    )  AS [GroupBy1]
                )  AS [Project1]
            )  AS [Project2]
        )  AS [Project3]
    )  AS [Project4]
)  AS [Project5]
  )  AS [Project6]
```

Comment: Why don't you create a view and filter the data through that?

Comment: Mostly, I want to use Linq . But I take into account . It can be an approach

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for things like this, Linq does not perform particularly well. You're better off working through stored procedures.

I would group by status type, project to an anonymous type, then parse that into a new object outside of Linq (Untested)

```
var query = from p in sentMailPagingBiz.FetchMulti()
            join s in emailAddressBiz.FetchMulti() on p.Id equals s.SentMailPaging_Id
            where p.SentMail_Id == 5648
            group s by new { s.SentMailPaging_Id, s.Status_Id}
            into g
            select new { g.Key.SentMailPaging_Id, g.Key.Status_Id, Count = g.Count() };
```

you parse the results of this by

```
var result = query.Select(g => new
        {
            All = g.Sum(s => s.Count),
            ReadyToSend = g.Where(s => s.Status_Id == 1).Select(s => s.Count).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
            Sent = g.Where(s => s.Status_Id == 2).Select(s => s.Count).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
            Rejected = g.Where(s => s.Status_Id == 3).Select(s => s.Count).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
            Queued = g.Where(s => s.Status_Id == 4).Select(s => s.Count).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
            SoftBounce =g.Where(s => s.Status_Id == 5).Select(s => s.Count).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
            HardBounce = g.Where(s => s.Status_Id == 6).Select(s => s.Count).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum(),
        });
...
```